# Limit number of JWT token per minute

Tags: java, api, rest, jwt, access-token

I have a system where users get authentication token after valid credentials. that token can be used for further operations. Now I want to limit the number of tokens. I want that system should only generate 20 tokens per minute, Is there any simple way to do that?  I'm thinking of a thread or infinite loop that increases the count on every token generation until count is less than 20 and after 1 minute it reset the count.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Depends on the context. Is this a single server or are there multiple deployments?

Answer (score 0):

With the informations you gave us, i think you have your own system (DataBase, FrontEnd and BackEnd) on your control.

So, you generate some JWT token, what is bloking you to store an counter, who you will increase each time your mono or multi system will generate an JWT, before generate it, you check your counter and an variable who will store your last datetime generation to check if during the last minute elapsed, your limit didn't reached.